# How do I order by the sum of two rows, in MySQL, for each user

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that is Scoreboard.

```
userID|userName|weekID|pickID|Score
--------------------------------------------
1     |Bob     | 1    | Den  | 10
1     |Bob     | 2    | Clev | 20
2     |Adam    | 1    | Car  | 12
2     |Adam    | 2    | Den  | 30
```

I would like to sort the table by the sum of all of the weeks
My desired result would be this.

```
 userID|userName|weekID|pickID|Score
--------------------------------------------
2     |Adam    | 1    | Car   | 12
2     |Adam    | 2    | Den   | 30
1     |Bob     | 1    | Den   | 10
1     |Bob     | 2    | Clev  | 20
```

Adams entries are on top because the sum of his score for Week 1 and Week 2 
is the highest. The whole table needs to be sorted this way, so while Im spitting out the HTML on a loop, the rows will be sorted in order.

Comment: So show us your query as we will suggest amendment

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the aggregate score per user and sort by that total in descending order, and optionally one or more other columns as well.  I assume `weekID` is a good secondary sort.

You can `JOIN` the table to itself based on `userID`, `GROUP BY` the main table's `userID` and `weekID`, and `SUM` the `JOIN`ed table's `Score` column in order to be able to `ORDER` correctly.

```
SELECT s.userid, s.username, s.weekid, s.pickid, s.score, SUM(a.score) totalscore
FROM scoreboard s
INNER JOIN scoreboard a ON a.userid = s.userid
GROUP BY s.userid, s.weekid
ORDER BY totalscore DESC, s.weekid;
```

If you don't need the total in the data returned you can put the `SUM` directly in the `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT s.userid, s.username, s.weekid, s.pickid, s.score
FROM scoreboard s
INNER JOIN scoreboard a ON a.userid = s.userid
GROUP BY s.userid, s.weekid
ORDER BY SUM(a.score) DESC, s.weekid;
```

I assume your data is more normalized than this, so adjust accordingly.

I also imagine that you plan on operating for more than just a single season, so you may eventually need to filter on that as well.

Comment: this should be marked as the correct answer. 2nd query is exactly what the OP asked for =)

Answer (score 0):

The "GROUP BY" ist the key. The following should work:

```
SELECT userID, SUM(Score) as TotalScore
FROM teh_table
GROUP BY userID
ORDER BY TotalScore DESC;
```

Comment: This query is not enough

Comment: This will get you the correct order of users but that is just the start as it will give you 2 rows for the OP's example.

Comment: @jeroen, please look at the desired result in the question

Comment: @Mojtaba I have, what do you mean?

Comment: @jeroen, he doesn't want to users be grouped. he wants the exact number rows as they are. For example, in your result, we would have only 2 rows in result. Whereas he wants all 4 records

Comment: @Mojtaba Ummm, yes, that's what I said in my first comment...